# How to render html variable in knockout js

Tags: magento, knockout.js

maybe somebody met this issue

I need to render html variable in ko template outside html element

I wrote that code in template

```
<!-- ko html: test_variable --><!-- /ko -->
```

And knockout gave an error

The binding 'html' cannot be used with virtual elements

I setted

```
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['html'] = true;
```

Knockout ceased to show error, but nothing was rendered

I use knockout in magento and tried magento custom bind type 'bindHtml', but got the same

Maybe somebody knows way, how will be possible to render variable that way?

Comment: Why do you need to use a virtual element? You should be able to use a div instead `<div data-bind="html: test_variable"></div>`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?